# MathML to LaTeX conversion

Tags: java, javascript, latex, xml-parsing, mathml

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a MathML representation of a math equation and convert it to the LaTeX representation of that math equation. So for example...

```
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow><mi>x</mi></mrow>
      <mrow><mi>y</mi></mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

... is a simple stacked fraction and it's LaTeX representation would be...

```
\frac{x}{y}
```

I'm guaranteed that the MathML has no presentational markup because I am constructing the MathML string dynamically and I control how/where the MathML elements are inserted; the MathML string is just pure structure of the math equation.

So my question is, are there any Java/JavaScript libraries out there that can take a MathML input string, like the one above, and generate the corresponding LaTeX string? I would much rather not have to write this parser myself. If not Java/JavaScript, are any libraries at all that can do this?

If not, any suggestions on how to approach this problem of writing my own parser? Where to start, things to consider, resources, etc...?

### UPDATE

Thanks to [Optimal Cynic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541451/optimal-cynic), I was able to use [this Java library](http://www.tilman.de/programme/mathparser/download_en.html) to do what I want. It is not perfect however, but I can easily modify it and make it work well. However, I would still like to see this done in JavaScript. So are there any tools like this written in JavaScript? If not, I'll resort to translating it myself.

Note: I am using [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render the MathML on the page, but MathJax does not currently support a way to go from MathML to LaTeX. It can only go from LaTeX to MathML.

Comment: If you ever implement this in JavaScript, be sure to share a link to the implementation here.

Comment: @Mikko... will do, and I'll probably open source it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try http://www.tilman.de/programme/mathparser/anleitung_en.html - it's written in Java and the source is available.

Comment: This is cool. The only problem is, its a desktop application and I need a web-based way to do this. Do you know if the source for this is available? +1

Comment: Yes, the source is available. Go to the download link and at the bottom there's a link to the source code.

Comment: hmm... sweet! this should be able to do the trick. I'll try to implement this in JavaScript since I need it on the web.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with XSLT, SAX parsers, or DOM parsers?

Bindings for SAX and DOM parsers exist for all major languages (and pretty much every other language too). I would recommend DOM parsing using a functional language, but tastes differ.

XSLT is a functional language designed for processing XML.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with those. I'm just trying to figure out how to construct the LaTeX string so if I can't find a library to do that for me, I'll resort to using the DOM parser probably (or SAX, haven't decided which is more beneficial to my case). the parsers alone can't build LaTeX strings right?

Comment: @Hristo: Obviously, you use them to write your programme, but it's a very simple translation.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and mathparser provided in url from question wasn't working for me at all.

I converted MathML to LaTeX by using [XSLT MathML Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsltml/) with [Saxon-HE](http://saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml) but since XSLT MathML library is pure XSLT any XSLT transformation tool should handle it. 
Output is not always perfect but it gave me better results than [web-xslt](https://code.google.com/p/web-xslt/wiki/Overview) mentioned somewhere at stackexchange network.

Command line usage with saxon:

```
saxon -o output.tex input.mml xsltml_2.1.2/mmltex.xsl
```