# Convert MathML to Latex

Tags: xslt, latex, transformation, mathml

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587864/mathml-to-latex-conversion) post, I tried to convert the MathML example, which looks like this:

```
<math>
  <mrow>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow><mi>x</mi></mrow>
      <mrow><mi>y</mi></mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

to Latex using [`xsltproc`](http://fhoerni.free.fr/comp/xslt.html). First I downloaded the XSLT files from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsltml/). Now, for those of use who don't speak MathML, the above example is a fraction: 1/2

After I've unzipped the xslt file and I created the MathML file (input.mml) I have the following files:

```
$ ls
README  cmarkup.xsl  entities.xsl  glayout.xsl  input.mml  mmltex.xsl  scripts.xsl  tables.xsl  tokens.xsl
```

So, when I do

```
$> xsltproc mmltex.xsl input.mml




                    x


                    y
```

Which is not correct, its not a Latex fraction. Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only getting the text content as the result of a transformation very often indicates that none of the templates in the stylesheet were applied. Then, buil-in templates step in and skip everything except for text nodes, which are sent to output.

Looking at the stylesheets you use, the stylesheets assume that the MathML input is in a *namespace*. For example, look at this template match I have taken from the *mmmltext.xsl* stylesheet:

```
match="m:math[not(@mode) or @mode='inline'][not(@display)] | m:math[@display='inline']">
```

As you can see, the elements are *prefixed* with `m:`, and, more interestingly, `m:` is declared as

```
xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
```

On the other hand, the input file you show is not in any namespace. Try the following input file:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mrow>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow><mi>x</mi></mrow>
      <mrow><mi>y</mi></mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

In the XML document above, I have declared a *default namespace* on the `math` element. All of its child elements also take on this namespace.

Then, the output contains:

```
\frac{x}{y}
```

---

As the  [W3C page says](http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML/):

> Typical usage [of this namespace] would be:
>
> `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a quick way to achieve this online.

The below is a link to an npm package that converts MathML to LateX.
https://npm.runkit.com/mathml-to-latex

Simply copy, paste and run